# Deleting original photos from iPhone

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

I am out of space on my iPhone, and want to delete photos after moving them to a laptop folder.

I can't do this from the Photos app, because the iCloud update seems to have hung on either a corrupt image file or one that is so big it takes more than ten hours to upload.

I thought the solution would be to Browse them with GraphicConverter but not only is something keeping it from viewing all photos, it is showing the originals of photos that have been edited on the iPhone (along with the edited version.)

I would like for the originals of edited photos to go away.  If I hit "Done" instead of "Cancel," that means I like my edits and have ***NO*** reason to waste space on the original.

**Is there some arcane secret way to get rid of the pre-edit version?**

I cleared out the deleted items on the phone, so that's not where they're coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Use Image Capture to access the photos on your iPhone, move them to your laptop, then delete them. You can even delete the photos from the iPhone from within Image Capture itself.

Comment: This assumes that what is on the phone is actually the image, and not the thumbnail (since the OP says they're using iCloud Photo Library).

Comment: Imge Capture can only find one photo on the iPhone.  It's one that I could not find in either Photos app nor with Graphic Converter.  And Image Capture is not able to delete it.

Comment: Looks like file corruption on the iPhone itself. Try the free trial version of [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) to see if you can get access to the photo. Have you turned off iCloud to see if it frees up the file?

Comment: It’s possible, though weird that the phone would be able to display all of the images, let not allow connected apps to even note their existence.  And Photos on the laptop can display Photos that give errors when I try to export them.